# load page two by default when gridview loads on pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load the second page of the gridview by default when the page loads. Is that possible?

```
//Loads when they page loads
    protected void BindDataExpense()
    {
        dsExpenseTable = objexp.GetCommissionBreakDownTable(name, breakdownType);
        gridlist.DataSource = dsExpenseTable.Tables[0];
        gridlist.DataBind();
    }

//changes the page number
protected void PageIndexChangingExpense(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    dsExpenseTable = objexp.GetCommissionBreakDownTable(name, breakdownType);
    gridlist.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridlist.DataSource = dsExpenseTable.Tables[0];
    gridlist.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the PageIndex of the gridList after the binding line in an update panel?

Comment: I have not. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I've added this code to my gridview the pageindex and pagesize

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridlist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"  AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="35" PageIndex = "1">
```